# testReport destinationDir is deprecated in gradle 7.4.2 so how to set it?

Tags: gradle, junit, deprecation-warning

```
task<TestReport>("testReport") {
    destinationDir = file("$buildDir/reports/allTests")
}
```

This is apparently deprecated, but the deprecation message doesn't make sense to me in this context. How am I actually supposed to set this value now?

```
    /**
     * Sets the directory to write the HTML report to.
     *
     * <strong>This method will be {@code @Deprecated} soon, please use {@link #getTestResults()} instead to access the new collection property.</strong>
     */
    public void setDestinationDir(File destinationDir) {
        DeprecationLogger.deprecateProperty(TestReport.class, "destinationDir").replaceWith("destinationDirectory")
            .willBeRemovedInGradle8()
            .withDslReference()
            .nagUser();
        getDestinationDirectory().set(destinationDir);
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense because attempting to use this new property results in compiler errors

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please try like this.

Older version:

```
destinationDir = file("$buildDir/reports/tests/test")
```

With latest version:

```
getDestinationDirectory().set(file("$buildDir/reports/tests/test"))
```

It worked for me. Hope it'll work for you. Thanks

Comment: destinationDirectory.set(file("$buildDir/reports/allTests"))
worked for me and looks more idiomatic IMO

Answer (score 0):

`$buildDir` has also been deprecated but the good news is that you can collect all your subproject's test reports using `test-report-aggregation` plugin.

In Gradle 8.5, I've removed the following snippet from my parent `build.gradle`:

```
task testReport(type: TestReport) {
    destinationDir = file("./reports/allTests")
    // Include the results from the `test` task in all subprojects
    reportOn subprojects*.test
}
```

and created a separate subproject, say **test-results**, with the following `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
     id 'base'
     id 'test-report-aggregation'
}

dependencies {
     testReportAggregation project(':subprojectA')
     testReportAggregation project(':subprojectB')
     testReportAggregation project(':subprojectN')
}

reporting.baseDir = "../reports/allTests"

test.finalizedBy('testAggregateTestReport')

run.enabled = false
```